# Aruco Marker detection ist not working with dark background

Tags: python, opencv, detection, marker, aruco

I'm trying to detect Aruco markers with a drone camera.
Now at first try it was successful and the detection worked from 40-50 m above the ground.

Yesterday I printed some other Aruco Markers. But now it's not working with these new printed markers.

[image: Picture of my Problem (Example)]

So my question:

If the background black or dark is the detection not working well? Should I print the Marker with a white frame around?
I tried both using different printers. Maybe that's a reason because intensity of the black was not as like the first printed markers

I don't understand why it's not working because the other markers from the first trying were detected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Aruco markers require white border to be segmented.